# как сохранить класс добавленный элементу при переходе на другую страницу

Tags: javascript, jquery

Это мой домашний проект.Пробовал через localStorage не чет не догнал как это реализовать...

```
$( ".myCheck" ).click(function() { 
    $(this).toggleClass('jquery-checkbox-on'); 


    if($(".myCheck").hasClass('jquery-checkbox-on')){ 
           content = $( "div.props:contains('Нет в наличии')" ).parent().parent().detach(); 
    }else { 
        content.appendTo(".b-grid-iaCtqJ7Nfn");
    } 
});
```

Comment: как то ваш код не слишком связан с вопросом в заголовке и текстом. Вы тот кусок кода нам скопировали?

Comment: действительно, как на новой странице получить данные фронта, выполненные фронтом другой страницы... вы немножко недопонимаете как устроенно. нельзя просто так взять и передать фронт одной страницы к другой. как вариант если вам нужно сохранить результат работы js вы можете сделать ajax после добавления класса элементу. в запросе нужно передать название класса. далее на back сохранить это название куда нибудь. А вот уже на новой странице начать с того, что сделать ajax. который спросит "а че там сохранено то?". back залезет туда где сохранялось посмотрит и вернет. и  js проставит этот класс.

Comment: @Дмитрий вполне себе можно сохранить  настройки в `localStorage`. Если пользователь выбирает цвет кнопки, то `localStorage` будет вообще оптимальным местом чтобы хранить его при переходе между страницами.

Comment: :D узнал про localStorage. ну тогда https://tproger.ru/articles/localstorage/ там вроде ничего сложного.

Comment: @Дмитрий там еще `sessionStorage` есть.

Comment: у вас php или html страницы? Не думали юзать get или post?

Comment: @teran да да я почитал, спасибо)